# one the one hand, on the other with more than one sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

I am wondering if you can do something like this:

On the one side, feeding an additional mouth often forced families into living on the breadline. Killing a further member of the family was often preferred to ensure acceptable living conditions for the existing children (163). In this sense, infanticide was seen as an option of birth control when contraceptives were not available or other preventive measures had failed (163).

On the other side,... :)

I know it´s a monstrous sentence. Can I do that or is it limited to one sentence a specific number?

Comment: Yes, of course you can, provided the sentences make sense.

Comment: Yes, of course you can, provided the sentences make sense. And be careful with "the one side," which may suggest a faction rather than an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, but you might not need to.

You don't need any introductory phrase for the first paragraph. You don't need to use "On the other hand" (or "On the other side", which is less common) in the second. You could use "However" or another linking word to show contrast:

> Feeding an additional mouth... . However, the Church condemned... .